# What is the Buddhist term for each moment being subtlety unique?

Tags: reference-request, terminology, sunyata, time

Read it a long time back, I remember it had something to do with someone meditating in a field of grass, and watching the wind go through the individual blades of grass and how they swayed.

It was a specific term and dealt with emptiness and the uniqueness of each passing moment.

Comment: Not sure which branch/school or if term is in multiple...

Comment: There's a poem, "[Inch Time Foot Gem](http://www.ashidakim.com/zenkoans/32inchtimefootgem.html)". Are you looking for a single word, or a phrase? And do you know in which language: English or ...?

Comment: Great poem! Looking for a single word term. Not sure the language, would have been 2007ish when I came across it...

Comment: Kshana,  [Chiththakshana][1], 


  [1]: http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/8884/5513

Comment: @Shrawaka thanks, that is incredibly related, but not quite what I'm looking for....

Comment: Poem: "The Summer Day" by Mary Oliver. Heart Sutra - same thing. Nonduality. Non-Symbolic Consciousness (research field).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe the term is "Tathata" that means "suchness" or "thusness". It is a Mahayana term. It means "Things as they are" or "reality". It's ultimate reality as opposed to conceptual reality.

It comes from the word the Buddha used to describe himself," Tathagata" that means "one thus gone".

> In Chan stories, tathātā is often best revealed in the seemingly mundane or meaningless, such as noticing the way the wind blows through a field of grass, or watching someone's face light up as they smile.
>   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tath%C4%81t%C4%81